# problema con Pseudo-elementos ::before y ::after en css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, sass

Saludos, estoy tratando de centrar la flecha que realizo con los pseudo-elementos `:Before` y `:after` de css pero no encuentro como resolver mi problema, la idea es que la flecha se centre al `div` que lo contiene y que la flecha no cambie de posición sin importar el numero. Quedo atento a cualquier recomendación para realizar este tipo de flechas.

```css
.container1 {
    color: #727176;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 6px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container1::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    left: 26px;
    top: 19px;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container1::after {
    content: "";
    top: 30px;
    left: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-top: 12px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1" style="top: 60px;">
    <span>$990,000,000,000</span>
</div>
<div class="container1">
    <span>$990,000</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, reformula la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DanielDíaz a que te refieres con eso? que la cambie?

Comment: La pregunta debe de ser una pregunta, con signos de interrogante y eso :S

Comment: @DanielDíaz Eso no lo dice en ninguna parte. Quizá el título de la pregunta se pueda mejorar  haciéndolo más descriptivo del problema  pero no tiene porque ir entre signos de interrogación

Comment: Mira los ejemplos de "Bien" y "Mal"

Comment: Lo sé, son eso, ejemplos. Los malos no lo son porque no estén formulados como preguntas, sino porque no dan información precisa y relevante sobre el tema a tratar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rápidamente se me ocurre que sería una muy buena opción para usar `calc()` para variar la posición a la izquierda `left`, tomando como referencia el 50% y restándole la mitad del ancho que ocupa la "flecha". Seguramente quedarían pendiente algunos ajustes menores, pero la idea está plasmada a continuación:

```css
.container1 {
    color: #727176;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 6px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container1::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    top: 19px;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container1::after {
    content: "";
    top: 30px;
    left: calc(50% - 11px);
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-top: 12px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1" style="top: 60px;">
    <span>$990,000,000,000</span>
</div>
<div class="container1">
    <span>$990,000</span>
</div>
```

Comment: precisamente estaba pensando en algo con cal() pero no sabia como hacerlo, muy buena respuesta gracias !!!